# Is it possible to execute remote GUI process locally in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, remote, graphical-user-interface

I know that Linux can open - for example - a firefox window in a local pc as if it was a window opened remotely. Can I do the same thing in windows? 
N.B. I use PsExec but it can launch a program from local but it runs remotely.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1172816/equivalent-of-x11-forwarding-for-locally-displaying-gui-running-on-a-remote-wind

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to what you want is Remote Desktop Services. Also there are X server [implementations](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) for Windows so you can run Linux graphical apps remotely e.g. via SSH.

Comment: Thank you for the link you suggested. Interesting. But I wanted something that would allow me to do it with the tools already included in Windows.